# multiple str_replace in given output (PHP)

Tags: php, string, scrape

Really bad at PHP. Learning it. I have an output here that's from scraped data. Data is scraped and saved in a cache file under the name nationalhi. In the output, there's an undesirable "2)", so I put in an str_replace and it's getting rid of it succesfully. Thing is, there's also a "5)" I'd like to get rid of, but everytime I try and combine two str, it breaks the code, because I'm doing something wrong. Any suggestions/help? Thanks very much.

Working code with one single str replace function:

```
file_put_contents(globalVars::$_cache_dir . "nationalhifour", 
str_replace('Low', ' ', $ret_[39]));
```

Two STR replaces, not working:

```
 file_put_contents(globalVars::$_cache_dir . "nationalhi", str_replace('2)', 
' ', str_replace('5)', ' ', $ret_[35]));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> mixed str_replace ( mixed $search , mixed $replace , mixed $subject [,
>   int &$count ] ) If search and replace are arrays, then str_replace()
>   takes a value from each array and uses them to search and replace on
>   subject

for more info look at [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)
here is an example

```
echo str_replace(['1','2','3'],['100','200','300'],'the strings  1 2 3 are replaced successfully ');
// output the strings 100 200 300 are replaced successfully
```